# Why does my laptop battery die after 5 minutes with Ubuntu?

Tags: power-management, battery

I'm new to Ubuntu but wanted to replace Windows 10 on my old laptop with something faster.

I've installed Ubuntu 18.04 and it's going ok so far except that the battery dies after about 5 minutes when the laptop is unplugged.

After some research it seems like it might be a video driver issue. However, I don't know how to find out if the correct driver is installed. My laptop is an Acer Aspire E1-571 with integrated graphics.

Can anyone help me diagnose this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Using `sudo lshw -C video` will list-hardware of class video; where you should see a driver= telling you what driver your hardware is using.

Comment: A laptop battery is not connected to the operating system. If your battery is dead within 5 minutes then that seems a hardware problem to me. "After some research it seems like it might be a video driver issue." why? Cuz this "My laptop is an Acer Aspire E1-571 with integrated graphics": is contradicting your previous statement.

Comment: Your battery and/or AC power adapter is defective. Also, don't replace Windows 10... you may need it to do things like BIOS updates, that you can't do in Ubuntu. Lastly, why didn't you install 19.04?

Comment: Try this command, you may need to replace `battery_BAT0` with `battery_BAT1` if no actual results  , `upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0`  Check out energy-full: vs. energy-full-design: and the capacity %

Comment: It does seem like a hardware issue but the battery lasted fine before I replaced Windows 10 with Ubuntu. (Maybe replacing Windows 10 was a bad idea but too late now!)

upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery/battery_BAT0 (andBAT1) didn't show any results.

Comment: The battery issue is probably a coincidence. It's an old laptop and if the battery is the original one then it really should be "dead" now. I somehow don't believe in *the battery lasted fine before I replaced Windows 10 with Ubuntu* at face value.

Comment: If upower doesn't show then install `acpi` and run `acpi -ib` .That should present some basic info plus a battery number

Comment: Thanks for the input.

acpi -ib shows (straight after unplugging laptop):
Battery 0: Discharging, 98%, 03:27:47 remaining
Battery 0: design capacity 4400 mAh, last full capacity 3611 mAh = 82%

However, it will only last about 5 mins in reality.